# I try to fetch user information from google api using access_token which provided by mobile end through web api but getting 401 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, google-api, asp.net-mvc-5.2

How to fetch user information in MVC5 from google API through access_token which token provided by the mobile end into web API?
[Used Code][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2hfW.png

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var urlProfile ="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + model.Auth;
client.CancelPendingRequests();
HttpResponseMessage output = client.GetAsync(urlProfile).Result;
if (output.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string outputData = output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Getting Error: If I am using above code to fetch user information by access_token

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve this issue:
I have used another API to fetch user info from google.
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=Auth